# separate chinese part and english part from a text document

Tags: java

I have a text document including both chinese and english. I would like to separate it into two parts, or two documents. One document just hold the chinese part and the other document just hold english part. Is there a way to do that in Java?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you give a sample of the document ? Is it a `.doc` file ... or `.pdf` or.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with regex, the part that validate the pattern with alphabetic english character go to a part, and the part that dont validate to the other part. I supose that the two parts are in different parts (not mixing both partd), perhaps if they are mixed you could have the problem of the common characters (, . ? etc...), perhaps for this characters you could see the before and the next character.

I think that this can be a possibility probably there are best ways to do that.

Edit: I supose that is a txt, but in another format only pass to txt before.